# UI objects of iphone app are not showing in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, user-interface, ipad

I am having universal app. And I have also followed the apple naming convention.

```
MyViewController~iphone.xib    //for iphone  
MyViewController~ipad.xib      //for ipad
```

When I run my iphone app into iPad some of the UIButtons and labels are not being shown.
What could be the workaround for this? Am i missing any changes so support the iphone app into ipad ?
Also my app is having different targets for iphone and ipad.

When i run the same app in iPad iOS6 device is it working fine.It is having issue with iOS5.

When I try to print the frame of all it gave me

```
"<UIImageView: 0x5ea9860; frame = (0 0; 1024 768); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x5ea9890>>",
```

for my background imageview of iphone app.

Comment: They are completely different xib:s or maybe I just didn't understand your question.

Comment: Is your lowest supported `iOS` 5? If so I would recommend switching to storyboards.

Comment: I can't switch to storyboard because project is almost ready.

Comment: I am just trying to ask that if we normally run the iphone application in ipad then it shows in 1x mode. but in my case it shows in 1x mode but its frames are showing 1024x768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming conventions by apple is working well..

```
MyViewController~iphone.xib    //for iphone  
MyViewController~ipad.xib      //for ipad
```

I just need to test it with different ipa for iPhone and iPad and run both ipa in iPad and is working well now.

I was saving the last bundle identifier in the schema and was showing the improper output.